# Doxygen displaying documentation within \page

Tags: doxygen

Within a C project, I have to document code in dedicated .dox files and not n the C file themselves.

Excerpt from a .dox file:

```
/*! \page intro2 Introduction2
Sample text

\fn void foo(void)
@brief foo

foo does nothing.
*/
```

The documentation will appear in the "file list" under the foo.h file where my function is defined. My page will only display the "Sample text" line.

Is there any way to get the documentation in the page itself, after the "Sample text" line?

I know I can achieve that with groups. But because groups and pages are not managed the same way by Doxygen, I'd prefer getting the doc in \page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
/*! \page intro2 Introduction2
Sample text

foo

foo does nothing.
*/
```

.h For foo

```
\fn void foo(void)
@brief foo
```

Not exactly what you want but I'm thinking it will all go in a page now with link that you can click to read about the function.  You might also be able to try to use [\copydoc](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc) if you really want the documentation to be in the page.

Comment: Thanks, but due to choices I cannot change, I cannot document in the source files. And I really want the documentation in the page, not accessible from the page.